# Error generating fakes with ITuple

Tags: .net, microsoft-fakes

We've been using the Microsoft Fakes framework in our solution for a long time to fake System.DateTime.UtcNow during testing.

More recently, though several weeks ago, we started using C# 7 features (with VS 2017), including tuples as return values from functions. Now, I created a new branch for a release. In the new branch, generating fakes fails with multiple of the messages below

`4>C:\Users\...\Source\... 2017\DEV\WebApp.UnitTests\f.cs(116674,53): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'ITuple' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [C:\Users\...\Source\... 2017\DEV\WebApp.UnitTests\obj\Debug\Fakes\m\f.csproj]
4>C:\Users\...\Source\... 2017\DEV\WebApp.UnitTests\f.cs(116674,13): error CS0538: 'ITuple' in explicit interface declaration is not an interface [C:\Users\...\Source\... 2017\DEV\WebApp.UnitTests\obj\Debug\Fakes\m\f.csproj]`

I have tried this:

- Add Microsoft.Net.Compilers 2.4.0 NuGet to all projects
- Upgrade all projects to target .NET 4.7 (from 4.6.1), and remove all System.ValueTuple references (seeing as those are now built-in to .NET 4.7)

I am not sure what else to try. We didn't encounter this issue when we first started using tuples and added the System.ValueTuple NuGet package. We only noticed the issue when creating a new branch. I suppose either the building of the FakesAssemblies or the restoring of NuGet packages must have triggered something.

Since then, we also noticed it happening when we Rebuild the solution.

**EDIT:** I have also tried to remove all Fakes assemblies, references, and configuration and starting over. Same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The solution turned out to be targeting .NET Framework 4.7.1. Per the docs (RTFM, I know...), `ITuple` is defined in `System.Runtime.CompilerServices` for the first time in that release:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.ituple(v=vs.110).aspx

> **.NET Framework**
>
> Available since 4.7.1

Answer (score 15):

You can ignore ITuple inside mscorlib.fakes file:

```
<Fakes xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/fakes/2011/">
  <Assembly Name="mscorlib" Version="4.0.0.0"/>
  <StubGeneration>
    <Remove FullName="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ITuple"/>
  </StubGeneration>
</Fakes>
```

*Note: `<StubGeneration>` element goes before `<ShimGeneration>` element

Answer (score 0):

I was getting these same errors referring to ITuple, but the mistake I made to cause them was rather silly. What fixed my build, for others who may have made the same mistake:

- Verify declared shims are in the correct .fakes file. For example, my DateTime shim:

  ```
  <ShimGeneration>
    <Add FullName="System.DateTime!" />
  </ShimGeneration>
  ```

  was accidentally placed in System.fakes instead of mscorlib.fakes.

Comment: However, problem persists when rebuild after cleaning the solution